# Unable to output an object once in a function using Array.filter with Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to create a search function using only Vanilla JavaScript. This works in the Browser's web console but I cannot get it to output the object once it is wrapped in the function.

I am having the user enter a search term in an HTML form. The form stores the value in a variable _searchInput, which is stored in session storage. When I am in the browser's web console and check the sessionStorag it returns the stored variable with the expected value. However, when I try to return the _results variable it returns an empty array.

Adding for clarity, the inputValue(); is a function that checks if the user entered a value and calls searchFunc(); if the search field is not empty.

The HTML

```
<form name="entryForm">
<input id="searchInput" type="text" label="Search" onclick="this.value = 
'' " />
<button id="searchBtn" onclick="inputValue();">Search</button>
<p id="response">I'm the value</p>
</form><br><br>
```

The Object Array

```
const allInvItems = [{
"ProdId": "1",
"InvItemName": "T-shirt",
"GinNum": "640041 - T-shirt",
"QtyServUnit": "1",
"QtyCountUnit": "1",
"PurchUnit": "EA - Each",
"CountUnit": "EA - Each",
"SellUnit": "EA - Each",
"CountFrequency": "D - Daily",
"StandCost": "10.6049"
 }, 
 { 
 "ProdId": "2",
 "InvItemName": "Shorts",
 "GinNum": "75043011 - Shorts",
 "QtyServUnit": "8",
 "QtyCountUnit": "1",
 "PurchUnit": "PK - Pack",
 "CountUnit": "EA - Each",
 "SellUnit": "EA - Each",
 "CountFrequency": "D - Daily",
 "StandCost": "2.6049"

 }];
```

The search function: this is where I am having trouble. I 
    function searchFunc() {

```
const storedInput = sessionStorage.getItem('_searchInput').value;

let _results = allInvItems.filter(function(obj) {
return obj.InvItemName == storedInput;
});

}
```

I am expecting it to filter out all other objects except that stored in the variable which is captured.

Comment: You cannot store anything except strings in Storage. Strings do not have a `value` property, so `storedInput` is `undefined`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code that reproduces the problem you are seeing. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the sessionStorage `_searchInput` key value incorrectly. In order to access the key value in  `sessionStorage`, use `sessionStorage.getItem('_searchInput')`.

```js
const allInvItems = [{
    "ProdId": "1",
    "InvItemName": "T-shirt",
    "GinNum": "640041 - T-shirt",
    "QtyServUnit": "1",
    "QtyCountUnit": "1",
    "PurchUnit": "EA - Each",
    "CountUnit": "EA - Each",
    "SellUnit": "EA - Each",
    "CountFrequency": "D - Daily",
    "StandCost": "10.6049"
  },
  {
    "ProdId": "2",
    "InvItemName": "Shorts",
    "GinNum": "75043011 - Shorts",
    "QtyServUnit": "8",
    "QtyCountUnit": "1",
    "PurchUnit": "PK - Pack",
    "CountUnit": "EA - Each",
    "SellUnit": "EA - Each",
    "CountFrequency": "D - Daily",
    "StandCost": "2.6049"

  }
];

sessionStorage.setItem('_searchInput', 'T-shirt');
const storedInput = sessionStorage.getItem('_searchInput');

const output = allInvItems.filter(({
  InvItemName
}) => InvItemName === storedInput);
console.log(output);
```

Note - Run the code in your browser.

Comment: Just one question, where the String 'T-Shirt' is can I just include the variable name since that value should be changing depending on the user entered value?                                                  
                              sessionStorage.setItem('_searchInput', 'T-shirt');

Comment: @Simcha13 - Where?